# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I keep seeing a memory exhausted error

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268 435 456 bytes exhausted

in my log file.

This error comes randomly even when the server is very lightly loaded & not reproducible on localhost. I have a VPS 4 server from hostgator with with loads of MB. The php config allows upto 256 Mb.

The code is below

```
function func_select_array($qry)
{
    $i=0;
    $data=array();
    $qry_result=mysql_query($qry);

    if($qry_result)
    {
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result))
        {
            $data[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    else 
    {
      return 2;
    }
}


    function func_check_rule_out_bid($auc_id,$bid_amount,$return_freq,$recheck)
    {
        $bid_qry="select * from tbl_bid where ubaid='".$auc_id."' and ubf='1' order by uba desc limit 0,10";
        $bid_array=func_select_array($bid_qry);
    }
```

The table tbl_bid has 2800 records. 
I get memory exhausted error in the while loop inside func_select_array function. 
I cannot imagine this query needs 256M+. It does not appear to be a php problem, but something in mysql. Please help...

Comment: At which line exactly are you getting the error. And rest assured that is related to PHP, not mysql. If it would be mysql, the server would not return a result. But you should validate if you send the right query.

Comment: 2800 records is probably OK. What is the size of each record? Do they contain `BLOB`s?

Comment: First order of business is to recreate the error. Failing that, log everything. If possible, log the query, result of `mysql_num_rows()`, `memory_get_peak_usage()`, and anything else before memory runs out. Then, next time it occurs, you can review the query and number of records it was trying to iterate over. You might find something you wouldn't normally expect.

Comment: Are you sure func_select_array is not being called from elsewhere? Or lots of times for some reason?

Comment: You do a `select * from tbl_bid ` which means, if there is a field with a large amount of data (a single field in MySQL can be terabyte large), and you stuff it into PHP's memory - well, you can hit a limit. That's perfectly normal and depends on the amount of data you query.

Comment: @hakre: i'm seeing error at line while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result)). Most of the time it runs fine. But randomly i get memory errors like the one i have posted.  @ Salman: The table has 11 columns (5 ints, 4 varchars(255) 1 datetime & 1 double). @ Mike i think mysql_num_rows() should not matter because i'm limiting the output to 10 rows regardless of the number of rows "desc limit 0,10" . @ Ben: fun_select_array is not called anywhere. The error is being logged in a error.log by apache and its pointing at the same line while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result)). Any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

Memory exhaustion can be very difficult to debug because the error only tells you where the memory finally ran out, not where the bulk of it was used.

You could use a memory profiler, such as the one in Xdebug, to find where all that memory went.

Answer (score 0):

You should use EXPLAIN to youre query. To assure that youre not doing some heavy query(at first look doesnt seem).

At second way, may be are you getting some BLOB ot TEXT field that is too heavy. Not at your local, thats why your not able to get this at local enviroment.

Assure that youre not getting an infinte loop. Could be?

Use trace php errors and try/catch this block to get better information about the error.

```
try {
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result))
        {
            $data[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }

} catch (Exception $e) {
   debug_print_backtrace(); 
   var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Hello. The query is not large. The table has 11 columns (5 ints, 4 varchars(255), 1 datetime & 1 double). I dont think i'm getting into infinite loop, because this is query is doing fine most of the time. The memory error is coming randomly. Also in the calling function i'm limiting the number of rows to 10. So how can there be a problem if just 10 rows are iterated all the time, regardless of the number of records in the table ? Can you please tell me how can i put try catch & log which query caused the memory error ?

Comment: Besides you could print youre query to see if theres no some strange thing somewhere.